# Is there a way to use more elements than display in an Out-GridView array

Tags: powershell

I am trying to allow a user to multiselect from a list of results returned from a command, using `Out-GridView`.

However, I seem to have to ask for the elements I need later on AND display them in the `Out-GridView`. But it gets chaotic in there!

Can I show less of them in the `Out-GridView`?

I have tried pulling in the command into another variable and then selecting the elements I want to show in the grid view, but that has the same result, or I am not doing it right.

For example:

```
$Global:delboxes = Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox | Select-Object Name,Alias,PrimarySmtpAddress,WhenSoftDeleted,ArchiveName,guid,Emailaddresses | Sort-Object -property Name | Out-GridView -Title "Please select mailbox(es)" -PassThru
```

Returns:

```
PS> $delboxes | ft
Name            Alias           PrimarySmtpAddress                  WhenSoftDeleted     ArchiveName Guid                                 EmailAddresses
----            -----           ------------------                  ---------------     ----------- ----                                 -------------- 
person1         person.one      person.one@mycompany.com            25/09/2016 20:53:56 {archive}   d25cb74b-46cf-4582-9c32-6c146f59f013 {X500:/o=mycompany/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/...
person2         person.two      person.two@mycompany.com            25/09/2016 20:53:56 {}          1670a21e-a00b-461e-ae84-2ff646e2a434 {SMTP:person.two@mycompany.com, smtp:person.2@mycompany, X500:/o=mycompany/ou=Exchan...
```

Although $delboxes will return everything I asked for in the Get-Mailbox | Select-Object part, there is too much to display on the screen when there are many EmailAddresses. So the Name and Alias get shrunk to a few characters

So I want just a few of the elements to show in the Out-GridView, but to be able to use them all later on in my script.

If I only put this in the script

```
$Global:delboxes = Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox | Select-Object Name,Alias | Sort-Object -property Name | Out-GridView -Title "Please select mailbox(es)" -PassThru
```

I am unable to use the element ArchiveName without requerying the `Get-Mailbox` command

```
PS> $delboxes | ft
Name            Alias
----            -----
person1         person.one
person2         person.two

PS> $delboxes.ArchiveName | ft
```

There is nothing :-(

And using default display set gives me an unusable Out-GridView and not the elements I require either

```
$Global:delboxes = Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox | Sort-Object -property WhenSoftDeleted | Out-GridView -Title "Please select mailbox(es)" -PassThru

PS> $delboxes | ft
RunspaceId                           Database           MailboxProvisioningConstraint IsMonitoringMailbox MailboxRegion MailboxRegionLastUpdateTime MessageRecallProcessingEnabled MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled MessageCopyForSendOnBehalfEnabled
----------                           --------           ----------------------------- ------------------- ------------- --------------------------- ------------------------------ --------------------------- ------
20edeed1-036f-4832-8463-486827c61405 EURP195DG024-db030                                             False                                                                     True                       False  False
20edeed1-036f-4832-8463-486827c61405 EURP195DG013-db099                                             False                                                                     True                       False  False
20edeed1-036f-4832-8463-486827c61405 EURP195DG007-db072                                             False                                                                     True                       False  False
```

Comment: `ft` (`Format-Table`) also has a `-Property` parameter - you can do `$delboxes | ft Name,Alias` if you want to see a table of just those properties :)

Comment: The `Select-Object Name,Alias` section of your pipeline is creating a copy of the object with _only_ the _Name_ and _Alias_ properties, discarding the rest, hence the _ArchiveName_ property isn't available later.  What do you get if you just send the output of `Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox` to the GridView (without any `Select-Object`)?  It should honour the default property set.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, but that is the reverse of the problem.
It is in the ```Out-GridView``` that I want to reduce the displayed elements, but being able to see/use them later - the ```$delboxes | ft``` is just to show what I have available in the variable after the ```-passthru```

Comment: Thanks boxdog, I did try this also. The default property set makes a huge mess, and doesn't include all the elements I need afterwards either.
(see update in question for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the Out-Gridview with only reduced properties and nevertheless afterwards have access to all properties,
you might save the selection and use `Compare-Object` with -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent

```
## Q:\Test\2019\03\27\SO_55377562.ps1
$Global:delboxes = Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox | 
    Select-Object Name,Alias,PrimarySmtpAddress,WhenSoftDeleted,ArchiveName,guid,Emailaddresses | 
    Sort-Object -Property Name 

$Selection = $delboxes | Select-Object Name,Alias | 
    Out-GridView -Title "Please select mailbox(es)" -PassThru

$SelectedDelboxes = Compare-Object -Ref $delboxes -Diff $Selection -Property Name,Alias `
               -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru |
    Select-Object * -Exclude SideIndicator
```

Comment: Spot on - that's it! :-)
Works perfectly, thank you so much LotPings

Comment: Thanks for feedback, `$SelectedDelboxes` now includes the property `SideIndicator` from `Compare-Object` you might remove with `Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty SideIndicator`

Comment: Hi LotPings, where would I put this ```-ExcludeProperty SideIndicator``` part? It doesn't like it as part of the ```Compare-Object``` and earlier than that, SideIndicator is not there

Comment: See changed answer.